# Class privada em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos, classes, visibilidade

Estou procurando um maneira de tornar invisível, tanto os atributos como os métodos, para não serem acessíveis de fora da class. Mas também eu queria usar a abordagem moderna para fazer isso (class NomeClass{}). Depois de muitas tentativas eu fiz uma abordagem diferente de tudo que encontrei: embora funcione exatamente como eu preciso, e, ao meu ver, fica muito mais simples e legível, não sei se isso é válido e/ou convencional.

Eu posso fazer isso? Ou existe alguma convenção que proíbe este tipo de abordagem?

Veja o código com atenção:

```js
'use strict';
//O objetivo dessa class é tornar os dados restritos
function ExemplePrivate(value){
    var _value = value; //Privado
    
    this.set_value = function(val){
        //Poderá fazer uma validação antes
        _value = val;
    }
    this.get_value = function(){
        //Poderá fazer uma validação antes
        return _value;
    }
}

//Class filha que será pública
class ClassPublic extends ExemplePrivate{
    //adicional code
}

 
    var cPublic = new ClassPublic('A class filha foi <b>instanciada</b>');
    document.querySelector('#p1').innerHTML = cPublic.get_value();
    cPublic.set_value('A class filha foi <b>modificada</b>');
    document.querySelector('#p2').innerHTML = cPublic.get_value();
    
    // Note que o resultado é bloqueado
    document.querySelector('#p3').innerHTML += cPublic._value+".";
```

```css
#p3{color:red}
```

```html
<!-- Look in JS -->
<p id="p1"></p>
<p id="p2"></p>
<p id="p3"> O resultado para <b>cPublic._value</b> tem que ser <b>undefined</b> porque é invisível: </p>
```

Comment: Parece me que a questão não é referente a classe privada mas sim a campos/métodos privados

Comment: Podes explicar melhor no teu exemplo, ao instanciar a classe `var cPublic = new ClassPublic` o que queres que seja visivel?

Comment: Note que esse exemplo tem o resultado como esperado. E, está funcionando corretamente. Respondendo sua pergunta: Somente _value deve ser privado, o restante são funções que o manipulam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Module Pattern

Pela descrição do problema, em que você quer separar a parte privada da parte pública, talvez o que você esteja procurando seja o *Module Pattern* ou algo semelhante. Eu já usei uma variação chamada [Definitive Module Pattern](https://github.com/tim-montague/Definitive-Module-Pattern) porque eu acho que fica mais clara a implementação. No link o autor também explica como funciona o padrão original.

Usando um exemplo:

```js
var module = (function () {

    function ClassePrivada () {
        this.valor = 30,
        this.setValor = function (val) {
          this.valor = val;  
        }
        this.getValor = function () {
          return this.valor;
        }
    }

    // private
    var _private = {
        valor: 10        
    };
    
    // public
    var _public = {
        getValor: function () { 
          return _private.valor
        },        
        setValor: function (val) {
          _private.valor = val;
        },
        getInstancia: function () {
          return new ClassePrivada();
        }
    };

    return _public;

})();


// funcoes privadas
console.log(module.getValor());
module.setValor(20);
console.log(module.getValor());

// classes privadas
var c = module.getInstancia();
console.log(c.getValor());
c.setValor(40);
console.log(c.getValor());
```

Você também pode criar uma hierarquia de módulos que é interessante e permite você organizar melhor seu código criando uma estrutura semelhante a namespaces.

Se não é exatamente esse tipo de solução que você procura, espero que te ajude na criação da sua solução.

Comment: Cara, esse código ficou muito claro, limpo e bonito. Mesmo não sendo na nova sintaxe, acho que ficou muito bom. Vou implementar esse seu código, ficou bem legal.

Comment: Eu também gosto desse desenho do Tim. Mas o padrão de módulo é o mesmo usado na implementação em TS na outra resposta. Eu coloquei essa resposta porque você comentou que queria algo em JS.

Answer (score 5):

Poder, pode. Faz o que deseja? Não tem efeitos indesejáveis? Só você pode responder isto. Se faz tudo corretamente pode fazer. Se não tem certeza certeza disso e que não faz nada diferente, não faça. Vale para qualquer coisa em programação. Nunca faça nada se não tiver certeza absoluta se o resultado é exatamente o que deseja, nem mais nem menos.

Não se importe com convenções que proíbem algo. Isto se chama "boa prática" e procure aqui no site o que eu acho sobre isto. Você tem que saber o porquê das coisas, não convenções que mandam você fazer algo.

Eu acho este código feio porque ele não usa classe de um lado e usa de outro. Se quer fazer a classe ser privada. Tenho minhas dúvidas se é o que quer. E acho que tem vícios neste código, mas isso é questão de opinião, até porque não sei bem o que quer e principalmente o que precisa que é mais importante do que quer.

Tem uma boa prática que diz para usar *getter* e *setter*, só que em linguagens de *script* isso faz pouco ou nenhum sentido.

Se quer classe programar em escala, onde precisa de classe privada deveria usar TypeScript. Exemplo de código:

```
module Modulo {
    export class ClassePublica {
        private classePrivada : PrivateClass;
        constructor() {
            this.classePrivada = new ClassPrivada();
        }
        public teste() {
            this.classePrivada.teste();
        }
    }
    class ClassPrivada {
        public teste() {
            console.log('it works');
        }
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/TypeScript/PrivateClass.ts).

Que em JS fica assim:

```
var Modulo;
(function (Modulo) {
    var ClassePublica = /** @class */ (function () {
        function ClassePublica() {
            this.classePrivada = new ClassPrivada();
        }
        ClassePublica.prototype.teste = function () {
            this.classePrivada.teste();
        };
        return ClassePublica;
    }());
    Modulo.ClassePublica = ClassePublica;
    var ClassPrivada = /** @class */ (function () {
        function ClassPrivada() {
        }
        ClassPrivada.prototype.teste = function () {
            console.log('it works');
        };
        return ClassPrivada;
    }());
})(Modulo || (Modulo = {}));
```

Comment: É por ser feio que fiquei com dúvidas se podia. Mas é simples e fácil de entender. Note que eu disse estou começando, então não faz muito sentido aprender TypeScript se eu ainda não entendo muito bem o JS. (É minha opinião). Vou analisar seu código para ver o posso melhorar. 
Ah! minha preocupação com a convenções é porque quero adotar boas práticas para evitar vícios rins.

Comment: É claro que se você colocasse o código comentado seria muito mais compreensível.

Comment: Coloquei o código do TS mais para ilustrar o que pode ser diferente, não é parte fundamental da resposta, e o código transpilado para JS é para ser ilegível mesmo. Não consigo imaginar porque não faz sentido aprender TS para quem está começando. Se aprender TS não precisa aprender JS. Acho que não leu direito minha resposta. Eu falei para não adotar boas práticas, porque elas criam vícios.

Comment: Se você pensar no fato que eu quero aprender JS, você vai entender porque não faz sentido aprender TS agora. Não quero que o compilador entenda nada por mim (Eu quero estar 100% no controle do código de produção). Isso só é uma opção pessoal, não tenho intenção em fazer nenhuma critica a quem vê o TS como uma solução.

Comment: Me tira uma dúvida: na sua opinião, seguir convenções é ruim? Foi isso mesmo que disse? Envia o link pra eu ver mais sobre essa questão.

Comment: Então não tente fazer em JS o que a linguagem não prevê. E sim, digo para não seguir convenções, isso dá muito errado para tudo, especialmente para resolver problemas que normalmente aparecem na computação. Digo para aprender para não ter que seguir convenções, que é ter controle de tudo, o mesmo que você disse no comentário, mas suas ações e outros discursos vão em direção contrária. Link para que?

Comment: Palavras suas: (Isto se chama boa prática e procure aqui no site o que eu acho sobre isto.) Eu não achei.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A101+%22boas+pr%C3%A1ticas%22

Comment: Eu entendi seu ponto de vista. Parece ser bem sensato. Vou procurar estudar a fundo todo código que eu utilizar nas minhas aplicações. Valeu.

Comment: @Maniero o ES6 tambem tem uma especificação para modules, então a menos que queira dá suporte ao IE11, não vejo por que não utilizar [Can I Use ES6 Modules](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module)