# Método privado em Classe JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos, método, ecmascript-6, ecmascript

Como definir um método privado em uma classe `JavaScript` de forma a tornar o método `msg_privada` como **privado** (não visível externamente) sem alterar o padrão de notação?

O método `msg_privada` deve ser acessado apenas pelo objeto da classe e não externamente.

```js
class TesteVisibilidade{

    // método público
    msg(input_msg){
      this.msg_privada(input_msg);
    }
    
    // método privado
    msg_privada(input_msg){
      alert('msg privada: ' + input_msg);
    }
}

let t = new TesteVisibilidade();
t.msg('Olá mundo!'); // emite alerta: "msg privada: Olá mundo!"
t.msg_privada('deveria dar erro!'); // Não deveria ser acessível (deveria resultar em ERRO)
```

Comment: Veja se essa resposta de outra pergunta te ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/328202/class-privada-em-javascript/328721#328721

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/428641/como-definir-atributos-privados-em-uma-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-construtora-utilizando-javascript

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como definir atributos privados em uma função construtora utilizando javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/428641/como-definir-atributos-privados-em-uma-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-construtora-utilizando-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Nas versões mais novas da linguagem, você pode declarar [campos e métodos privados](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_properties) em uma classe. É uma funcionalidade que [já possui um bom suporte dos *browsers* e *engines* atuais](https://caniuse.com/?search=private%20method).

Basta colocar o prefixo `#` antes do nome:

```js
class TesteVisibilidade {
    // método público
    msg(input_msg) {
        this.#msg_privada(input_msg);
    }

    // método privado
    #msg_privada(input_msg) {
        alert('msg privada: ' + input_msg);
    }
}

let t = new TesteVisibilidade();
t.msg('Olá mundo!'); // emite alerta: "msg privada: Olá mundo!"

// qualquer tentativa de usar o método privado fora da classe dá erro
// t.msg_privada('erro!'); // ERRO!
// tentando chamar com o prefixo
// t.#msg_privada('erro!'); // ERRO!
```

Repare que o método foi declarado como `#msg_privada`: o `#` no início indica que é privado. Vale notar que o prefixo `#` também é necessário ao se chamar o método: `this.#msg_privada(etc...)`. E como esperado, qualquer tentativa de usar o método privado fora da classe dará erro (com ou sem o prefixo, nenhum funciona).

---

Para quem está se perguntando "*Por que não usaram a palavra-chave `private` em vez do `#`?*", a resposta está [aqui](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-private-fields/issues/14) (houve uma discussão a respeito, com argumentos para ambas as opções, mas no fim o `#` venceu).

Answer (score 0):

Sem alterar o padrão de notação não é possível, você pode utilizar o typescript que adiciona vários conceitos de linguagens tipadas (Mas seu método não será private realmente, só que o typescript irá reclamar que você está tentando acessar um parametro/método privado, mas quando gerar seu javascript, poderá acessa-lo normalmente), ou usar o iife no js para criar um escopo para sua função/classe, exemplo utilizando o iife:

```js
(function(root){

 const camelCase = (nome) => nome.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + nome.substring(1, nome.length);

 class Pessoa {
  constructor (nome) {
   this.nome = nome;
  }

  get nomeCamelCase () {
   return camelCase(this.nome);
  }

 }

 root.Pessoa = Pessoa;

})(window);

//Não tenho acesso ao camelCase diretamente, somente ao Pessoa que adicionei no window
const nome = new Pessoa('jonathan').nomeCamelCase; // "Jonathan"
console.log(nome);
console.log(Pessoa);
console.log(camelCase);
```