# Como definir atributos privados em uma função construtora utilizando javascript

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos

Em javascript podemos ter as funções construtoras que são do tipo function, com elas podemos instanciar objetos como no exemplo a seguir:

```
function Pessoa(nome="Usuário Anonimo", idade = 00, cor) {
    //com o this podemos criar atributos e funções para serem acessados de forma pública
    this.falar = function() {
        console.log("Olá eu sou " + nome + " tenho " + idade + " Anos")
    }

    // podemos fazer os retornos de atributos da função por meio de métodos públicos ou até mesmo atributos públicos como this.nome = nome
    this.getCor = function(){
        return this.cor
    }

    this.setCor = function(cor){
        this.cor = cor
    }

}

const anonimo = new Pessoa
anonimo.falar()
anonimo.setCor("pardo")
console.log(anonimo.getCor())

// outra execução

const pedro = new Pessoa("Pedro ", 35, "Rosa")
pedro.falar()
// nesse caso a saída é undefined pois teríamos que definir this.cor = cor
// nesse caso iria referenciar a assinatura da function
console.log(pedro.getCor())
```

Em outras linguagens como Java podemos definir a visibilidade e permissibilidade de atributos por meio de palavras reservadas como: private, protected ou public e dependendo se for um ou outro podemos trabalhar em retornos diretos `instancia.atributo` ou `class.getAtribute` como podemos atribuir tais contextos dentro de uma função construtora?

Referência: [orientado a objetos mozila](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Javascript_orientado_a_objetos)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geralmente não se faz isso em JavaScript.

Existe uma [proposta](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) na fase 3 do EcmaScript para incluir o método de acesso privado nas classes, mas por enquanto é apenas isso, uma proposta.

Por convenção, muitos programadores utilizam um underscore no início da declaração de uma variável para indicar que tal propriedade não dever ser acessada diretamente, no seu exemplo seria `_nome` e `_idade`.

Alias, linguagens de programações diferentes, convenções diferentes. JavaScript possui propriedades, não atributos, `getCor` e `setCor` é uma convenção do Java para possibilitar a criação de uma lógica antes do acesso/atribuição de um atributo, mas em linguagens que utilizam propriedades, você raramente irá ver a utilização de métodos para implementar essa lógica.

Você pode implementar essa camada diretamente no [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) e no [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) das propriedades. Como a utilização de getters e setters em propriedades não requer a utilização de nenhuma sintaxe diferente, você só precisa implementar esses getters e setters se for utiliza-los. Não há a necessidade de cria-los previamente para evitar a eventual refatoração do código.

---

**Edit**

E então, menos de um mês após postar a resposta, a proposta foi aceita e agora é possível criar propriedades privadas em JavaScript com a seguinte sintaxe:

```js
class Retangulo {
  #altura;
  #largura;

  constructor(altura, largura) {
    this.#altura = altura;
    this.#largura = largura;
  }

  get area() {
    return this.#altura * this.#largura;
  }
}

const ret = new Retangulo(3, 5);
console.log('area:', ret.area);
```

Repare que `#altura` e `#largura` não são acessíveis fora da classe.

Esse nova funcionalidade já está disponível nas versões mais recentes dos navegadores baseados no Chromiun, no NodeJS, tão como em transcompiladores como Babel e TypeScript.

Answer (score 1):

Uma propriedade privada de uma classe é uma variável que só pode ser acessada por ela, certo? Então as variáveis `nome`, `idade` e `cor` já são privadas, já que só existem dentro da função, se você quiser criar outras sem receber como parâmetro, basta criar dentro de `Pessoa` com `var`, `let` e `const`

O que provavelmente está acontecendo é que você acredita que `cor` e `this.cor` são a mesma variável, porém não são, `cor` é uma variável que existe apenas dentro do escopo da função construtora, enquanto `this.cor` é uma propriedade do objeto `this` que é retornado ao instanciar e, portanto, é pública

Todas as propriedades de um objeto são públicas, ou seja, público é tudo que estiver no `this` e privado é o que for criado dentro da função. Os outros modificadores de acesso não existem, o nome do atributo pode ser prefixado com `_` quando aquela propriedade precisa ser pública para ser acessada fora da classe em outras funções do framework/biblioteca, porém o usuário (desenvolvedor) não deveria usá-las diretamente

Mas não entendi bem o que você deseja, se quer que `cor` seja pública, basta adicionar `this.cor = cor` ou até chamar `this.setCor(cor)` dentro da função `Pessoa`. Se quer que `cor` seja privada para ser acessada apenas pelos métodos *getter* e *setter*, basta trocar `this.cor` por `cor`